# Creating AWS lambda handler to execute Jasmine Runner

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, jasmine, aws-lambda

I am getting  "Process Exited before Completing request error with following handler.  Why is my callback not called after executing all test ?

> "errorMessage": "RequestId: 000e2a3b-8c5f-11e8-91f4-27bcbb5fbff8
>   Process exited before completing request" START RequestId:
>   16d47a14-8c61-11e8-b782-b7d39e21e674 Version: $LATEST
>   2018-07-20T21:08:46.755Z  16d47a14-8c61-11e8-b782-b7d39e21e674    Jasmine
>   started
>   2018-07-20T21:08:46.771Z  16d47a14-8c61-11e8-b782-b7d39e21e674    Tests
>   Test 2018-07-20T21:08:46.899Z 16d47a14-8c61-11e8-b782-b7d39e21e674
>   2018-07-20T21:08:46.899Z  16d47a14-8c61-11e8-b782-b7d39e21e674      Visit
>   website 2018-07-20T21:08:46.900Z  16d47a14-8c61-11e8-b782-b7d39e21e674
>   \u001b[32m✓ Visit Google\u001b[39m
>   2018-07-20T21:08:46.900Z  16d47a14-8c61-11e8-b782-b7d39e21e674
>   2018-07-20T21:08:46.901Z  16d47a14-8c61-11e8-b782-b7d39e21e674    Executed
>   1 of 1 spec\u001b[32m SUCCESS\u001b[39m in 0.147 sec. END RequestId:
>   16d47a14-8c61-11e8-b782-b7d39e21e674 REPORT RequestId:
>   16d47a14-8c61-11e8-b782-b7d39e21e674  Duration: 432.18 ms Billed
>   Duration: 500 ms  Memory Size: 3008 MB    Max Memory Used: 41 MB
>   RequestId: 16d47a14-8c61-11e8-b782-b7d39e21e674 Process exited before
>   completing request

My Handler

```
exports.handler = async (event, context, callback) =>{
const Jasmine = require('jasmine');
const { SpecReporter } = require('jasmine-spec-reporter');
const reporter = new SpecReporter();
const jasmine = new Jasmine();

jasmine.loadConfig({
  spec_dir: 'specs',
  spec_files: [
    '**/*spec.js',
],
  helpers: [
 ]
});

// Setup reporter
jasmine.env.clearReporters();
jasmine.addReporter(reporter);
const customReporter = {
specStarted(specInfo) {
console.log(`...Test: ${specInfo.description}`);
 },
};
//jasmine.addReporter(customReporter);

// TODO: Consider blocking log output for code outside of tests.

await jasmine.execute();
console.log(`Tests Test`);
callback(null, "success");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by adding onComplete function and doing the callback there. I also removed the "async" nature of the handler. I think there is more efficient way to do this, so let me know if any other suggestion

```
jasmine.onComplete(function(passed) {
 if(passed) {
 callback(null, "success")
 }
 else {
  callback(null, "failed")
 }
});
```